# Blocking selected websites

Tags: 18.04

I am running ubuntu 18.04.2 on a Toshiba Satellite laptop. I am trying to block certain websites using the command "sudo gedit /etc/hosts" The system cannot find "HOSTS"file.

Answer (score 0):

If the hosts file does not exist, then start with a new one.

I would run ...

```
sudo su
gedit /etc/hosts
```

Then inside the new file, add the following:

```
127.0.0.1    localhost
127.0.0.1    {whatever name you have for your machine}

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1          ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0      ip6-localnet
ff00::0      ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1      ip6-allnodes
ff02::2      ip6-allrouters
```

Save the file first and then you can go back to add to it.

If it gives errors trying to do the above, then it is not as straightforward.

Comment: I looked in the /etc folder and there IS a text file named "hosts", but the system still can't find it when I use "sudo gedit /etc/hosts.

Answer (score 0):

1. check (`ls /etc/hosts` or your file explorer that you have an `/etc/hosts` file (it should really be there, I have never seen a Linux system without one)
2. copy it to your user files (no `sudo` necessary)

   cp /etc/hosts ./etc-hosts
3. make a backup copy
4. edit it with a regular editor to add the blocked sites
5. copy the new version back (`sudo` needed):

   sudo cp etc-hosts /etc/hosts

Doing it that way:

- keeps a backup of an important file in case you foul things up
- lets you edit the file with your regular editor
- minimizes the time you spend doing sudo things (and avoids reusing the sudo-ed editor by mistake)
- keeps a copy of the new `/etc/hosts` in your own files, where is it a bit more likely to be backed up.

Comment: I have found a text file named "hosts" in the /etc folder. I cannot understand why the system says it can't find it when I use "sudo gedit /etc/hosts"

Comment: Tried again and the "hosts" file opened. The terminal screen had the following message  **(gedit:2760):WARNING**:19:44:26.251: set document metadata failed: Setting attribute metadata::gedit-position not supported

Comment: Really you should avoid editing the thing directly.

Comment: The error message came up even though I only opened the file